# Android - Indoor Pathfinding suggestions

Tags: android, path-finding, a-star

I'm working currently on a indoor pathfinding project. You can imagine it like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yE2QZ.jpg)

In my application i have two searchviews for a start room and a destination room, which i've already implemented. After entering the two rooms the application should start an algorithm, for example A*, to calculate the shortest path between these two rooms. Suddenly the user can see a drawn line between those two rooms.

Do you have any suggestions on how i can do this to implement an A* algorithm on Android like the picture shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A* algorithm rely on **graph theory**.

So, first you should plot your room as a graph (each room/floor is a vertex, or node, and each door is an edge). I suggest you use well-known implementations for that ([here](https://github.com/marcelo-s/A-Star-Java-Implementation) is an example).

Based on your schema, your graph should look like this

[image]

Keep a HashMap (or something else) to keep track of which room is mapped to which node, as well as which corridor is linked to which edge.

Then, when your use calls for a path, calculate your A* algorithm. The example I linked to you will look something like this

```
List<Node> path = aStar.findPath();
```

Remap back the List of nodes to a list of Rooms and show it to your user.

NB: If you want to make it very clean, you could re-write the `AStar.java` as to accept a list of `Room`, and make it spit out another list of `Room`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! It sounds feasible. I will try this approach. How do you created the graph? And do you know how i can draw the path for the user on android?

Comment: Well .. This depends how you show it on the screen (which technology/library you use). But basically, you have a set of nodes, you might draw straight lines inbetween them.  Don't forget to accept the answer if you feel it answered your question !